# Force pagebreak after every sentence/paragraph

Tags: page-breaking

Is there a way to force a pagebreak after every sentence or paragraph?  This may seem like an odd thing to do, but for catching typos and just general editing I find it much easier to look at a sentence or paragraph in isolation so that I am not tempted to skip ahead.  Currently, I just zoom in so I can only see a few word at a time, but this is not a perfect solution.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  You will have better luck hooking onto `\par` rather than inter-sentence spacing.

Comment: `\def\par{\newpage}` does not work here.

Comment: @Sigur `\newpage` wants to execute `\par`; do you understand now why your attempt fails?

Comment: @egreg, I could imagine when I read the error `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]`

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea, but you may want to try `\def\par{\endgraf\penalty-10000 }`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parskip = 50cm 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

I will include this in my new `killtrees` package `:)`

Comment: Nice! I would improve using `\parskip = \textheight`.

Comment: @Sigur, As far I can see, any measure enough big is equally perfect if less that `29.5\textheight` (a skip too big even for a frog).

Comment: Did you try those values to discover that?

Comment: @Sigur, five minutes ago  (just curiosity)  `:)`

Comment: @Fran thanks for the elegant solution.  I would definitely not print the document in this form :)  Just use it for editing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another, *less elegant*, solution playing around with the definition of `\par`. As pointed out in the comments this isn't so straightforward because all sorts of things end up calling `\par`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\realpar\par% save the real \par
% make \mypar insert page breaks but only *after* restoring the
% real value of \par and then revert \par --> \mypar
\def\mypar{\let\par\realpar\vfil\eject\let\par\mypar}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \let\par\mypar% needs to be after \begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

Quite possibly there are some unintended consequences of this!