# How do I format paragraphs to make a pagebreak?

Tags: page-breaking, parskip

How do I format the paragraphs so that it skips to next page. 
I would like each paragraph to be on a separate page, is something like this possible?

Comment: If you want just to move to next page you can do a `\newpage`. But I think that what you want should be done in a more elegant way. Please, edit the post and insert more information, maybe with some example.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate question: [Force pagebreak after every sentence/paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140359/force-pagebreak-after-every-sentence-paragraph)

As is proposed in answer to the linked question, you can set `\parskip` to any size between `\textheight` and `29.5\textheight`, to gain the desired effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parskip = \textheight
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```